# Get the URL from the folder where the file is saved

Tags: php

I have a question about the PHP $_SERVER[];

In the root directory I have a folder named site. In this folder I have an index.php file

The code below is written in the index file

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

If the user goes to https:[www.example.com/site](http://www.example.com/site) the request_uri is **/site**

If the user goes to https:[www.example.com/site/page](http://www.example.com/site/page) the request_uri is **/site/page**

So my question:

Is it possible to get the REQUEST_URI from the directory where the code is written?
Get request uri minus the upper folders the folder where the code is written is the start.

For example

If the user goes to https:[www.example.com/site](http://www.example.com/site) the request_uri is **/**

If the user goes to https:[www.example.com/site/page](http://www.example.com/site/page) the request_uri is **/page**

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing what you requested:

```
$parts = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])));
if (isset($parts[0]) && $parts[0] === 'site') {
    unset($parts[0]);
}
$url = implode('/', $parts);
echo '/' . $url; // /page
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$urlArray = explode("/",$url); 
$count = count($urlArray);
$str = "";
if($count > 2) // NOT AT THE ROOT //
{
    $str = $urlArray[$count-1];    
}
echo "/".$str;
```